# clearing input placeholder in iOS5

Tags: jquery, ios5, placeholder

I noticed that in iOS5, input placeholder text doesn't clear automatically on focus.

I tried this jquery function but it's not working:

```
$('input[type="number"]').focus(function(){
$('this').attr('placeholder','');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me the problem lies here

```
$('this').attr('placeholder','');
```

Try replacing:

```
$('this')
```

With

```
$(this)
```

Comment: Yeah! I just realized that stupid mistake and came back to fix or delete this question. I'll just leave it for anyone who makes the same mistake.. :) Thanks a lot!!