# iOS 5: Input placeholder doesn't clear on focus, only on input, bug or feature?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, cordova, mobile-safari

Playing around with my web application in the iOS 5 simulator, I noticed that iOS 5 doesn't clear placeholders immediately, only after the first input. On all other version of iOS as well as on all desktop browsers, the placeholder is immediately cleared when the user focuses on the input. I don't have access to an iOS 5 device right now but I highly doubt this is a simulator error.

Is this a bug or intended? Oddly I only found one reference to this behavior on the net, right here on SO: [clearing input placeholder in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282348/clearing-input-placeholder-in-ios5)

Is there a workaround for this problem? It's quite frustrating for the user when the placeholder doesn't clear immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaken - iOS text fields always behave this way.

I don't see why this would be frustrating for the user. If anything it is helpful that the helper text stays visible until they begin typing, in case they missed it before selecting the field.

What may be confusing you is that iOS fields have a separate optional behaviour where the text is cleared when the field is selected, but note that this is the *actual text* that clears, not the *placeholder* text.

Placeholder text is the light grey text, and this always appears until the user types something.

Content text (usually black) sometimes clears when the field is focussed and sometimes doesn't, depending on how the UITextField was configured.

The jQuery solution in the SO question you linked to should let you replicate any variant of this functionality that you desire, but personally I'd advise sticking with the iOS convention of not clearing helper text until the user types something.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought that this would be intended as I didn't find anyone else mentioning this on the web. I agree that it makes sense that the text stays there until the user starts typing, but as I said all other browsers behave differently and clear the text instantly. See for example [this demo](http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/html5-placeholder.php). I just checked on a bunch of recent (desktop) browsers.

Comment: Yep, it's an iOS platform standard, not a general web standard.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, it is a feature. You can use delegate methods to clear placeholder. (`UITextFieldDelegate` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [textField setPlaceholder:@""];
}
```

adn you should control its emptiness after finish editing.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    [textField setPlaceholder:@"Placeholder Text"];

}
```

Comment: The question was related to PhoneGap - i.e. the textfield is an html input field within a webview, not a native UITextField control.

Comment: @Nick-Lockwood: Thanks for clearing that up. It's not PhoneGap specific, as I noticed the behavior also occurs in Mobile Safari.

Comment: @mobweb anyway its an issue of UIWebView. That changes everything :)